# Unable to catch error thrown by Async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I was reading [this](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/) article. In the below code the async 'foo' function returns the result of the async 'waitAndMaybeReject' function.

I am unable to understand why the catch block in 'foo' function is not executed when 'waitAndMaybeReject' throws an error.

```js
async function waitAndMaybeReject() {
  
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));
  
  const isHeads = false;
  //const isHeads = true;

  if (isHeads) return 'yay';
  throw Error('Boo!');
}


async function foo() {
  try {
    return waitAndMaybeReject();
  }
  catch (e) {
    return 'caught';
  }

}
foo();
```

Comment: your returning an unfulfilled promise, so by the time it rejects, it will already be returned and you wont be able to catch it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `await` the `waitAndMaybeReject()` function in order to be able to catch the exception. As it is described in the article you refer to:

> By returning waitAndMaybeReject(), we're deferring to its result, so our catch block never runs.

To make it simple, when you `return waitAndMaybeReject()` you don't wait for it to resolve/reject in the `try ... catch` block.

Comment: Shouldn't  the code wait by itself because it is a return statement

Comment: No, if you return an async function without await you'll return a Promise.

Comment: No, the return statement, in this case, returns a pending promise unless you explicitly wait for it to settle by adding `await` operator.